# Update statement inside SqlDataReader loop not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqldatareader

I am running the following code. Following code is giving error on executenonquery line inside my SQL DataReader loop runs. I am getting

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

I have tried `mycomm.CommandTimeout = 600;` but it not helping.

I have executed these same statements in other projects it is working perfectly fine over there.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection myconn, myconn1;
    SqlCommand mycomm;

    myconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    myconn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    String q = "select * from addcart where sessionid=@sessid";
    mycomm = new SqlCommand(q, myconn);
    mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessid", Session["sid"].ToString());
    myconn.Open();
    mycomm.CommandTimeout = 600;
    SqlDataReader myreader;

    myreader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
    if (myreader.HasRows)
    {
        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            myconn1.Open();
            
            String qt = myreader["quantity"].ToString();
            String bookid = myreader["bookid"].ToString();
            q = "update addbook set stock=stock-@st where bid=@bid";
            mycomm = new SqlCommand(q, myconn1);
            mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", qt);
            mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bookid);
            mycomm.ExecuteNonQuery();//getting error on this line
            myconn1.Close();
        }
    }
    myconn.Close();
    

    myconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    q = "select * from newpayment where sessionid=@sessionid";
    mycomm = new SqlCommand(q, myconn);
    mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionid", Session["sid"]);
    myconn.Open();

    myreader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
    myreader.Read();
    Label2.Text = myreader["orderno"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = myreader["billamount"].ToString();
    Label4.Text = myreader["address"].ToString();
    myreader.Close();
    myconn.Close();      
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should convert the qt variable to number.

Comment: You use the same `mycomm` command in two different places. Create two commands.

Comment: Do not reuse `myreader`, `myconn`. Create as many variables as needed. Also you must Dispose resources.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the suggestions. I have tried it with multiple variables and multiple command instances also but still, it doesn't help. Any other suggestions??

Comment: I have also tried converting qt variable to number, but still, nothing makes any difference

Comment: Oh goodness!!! .. Instead of using a SqlDataReader, une a SqlDataAdapter and put all the data into a DataSet. The DataReader will keep the connection open while you are iterating over each record, this means you will have table/row locking issues if you try to perform updates while reading.

Comment: I'm not even going to ask why this is being done in a page load. The way I read this logic is that every time the page is loaded, the stock amount is reduced by the amount in the cart. I hope this page doesn't get reloaded more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the value to the command. I think this code might help you.

```
SqlConnection myconn;
SqlCommand mycomm;
SqlCommand rdrcmd;
myconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
String q = "select * from addcart where sessionid=@sessid";
mycomm = new SqlCommand(q, myconn);
mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessid", Session["sid"].ToString());
myconn.Open();
SqlDataReader myreader;
myreader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
if (myreader.HasRows)
{
    while (myreader.Read())
    {
        String qt = myreader["quantity"].ToString();
        String bookid = myreader["bookid"].ToString();
        qt="stock-"+qt;
        q = "update addbook set stock='"+qt+"' where bid=@bid";
        rdrcmd = new SqlCommand(q, myconn);
        rdrcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bookid);
        rdrcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    myreader.Close();
}
myconn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still not working. It is still the same. Any other suggestions?
I am getting the following error
Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.]

Comment: @Master now my answer get edited, try this one. I think this will solve your question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is because you use the same variables in different scopes.

Don't skimp on the variables. Just define a new one with clear names.

You must release the resources! This is done using the `Dispose` method or by wrapping them in the `using` statement.

See the modified code

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (var selectConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    selectConnection.Open();
    string selectSql = "select * from addcart where sessionid=@sessid";

    using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, selectConnection))
    {
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessid", Session["sid"].ToString());

        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                using (var updateConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    updateConnection.Open();

                    string qt = reader["quantity"].ToString();
                    string bookid = reader["bookid"].ToString();

                    string updateSql = "update addbook set stock=stock-@st where bid=@bid";

                    using (var updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, updateConnection))
                    {
                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", qt);
                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bookid);
                        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


using (var selectConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    selectConnection.Open();
    string selectSql = "select * from newpayment where sessionid=@sessionid";

    using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, selectConnection))
    {
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionid", Session["sid"]);

        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Label2.Text = reader["orderno"].ToString();
                Label3.Text = reader["billamount"].ToString();
                Label4.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also see [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) useful article.